# Use FallbackResource even if directory exists

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4

I've set up my virtual host on Apache 2.4.7 with a very basic configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  FallbackResource /index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Underneath the document root I have the following structure:

```
/index.php
/help/readme.txt
```

I get the following results when I make requests:

```
/bla     -> 200 OK
/help/   -> 404 Not Found
/help/a  -> 200 OK
```

It seems that the existence of the `/help/` directory is causing Apache to return `404` because there's no `index.php` in there, but I expect all requests to invoke `/index.php` and thus yield a `200 OK` response.

I don't remember this being a problem when using `mod_rewrite`, but I prefer using `FallbackResource` if possible. Is there a way to fix this?

**Update**

It works if I remove the `DirectoryIndex` directive, but that suffers from [five second delay issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/559067/apache-hangs-for-five-seconds-with-fallbackresource-when-accessing).

**Update 3**

I'm running the following test environment; the directory structure is as follows:

```
./htdocs
   index.html
   test/
      bla.txt
./conf
   httpd.conf
./logs
```

The contents of `httpd.conf` is:

```
ServerName apache-bug.local
Listen 8085

DirectoryIndex disabled
DirectorySlash Off

<VirtualHost *:8085>
DocumentRoot /home/user/apache-bug/htdocs

FallbackResource /index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

My `config.nice` contains:

```
"./configure" \
"--enable-debugger-mode" \
"--with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config" \
"--enable-dir=static" \
"--with-mpm=prefork" \
"--enable-unixd=static" \
"--enable-authn-core=static" \
"--enable-authz-core=static" \
"$@"
```

To run the server:

```
httpd -X -d /home/user/work/apache-bug/
```

Comment: And what is in the response body for `/bla`?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the problem then :-S

Comment: Just to make sure - which version of Apache are you on?

Comment: @JennyD I'm running on 2.4.7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm answering this myself as well, because I'm pretty sure that the issue is related to how `mod_dir.c` works [internally](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/mappers/mod_dir.c#L387) and I think it's [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56067).

If a resource can't be mapped to the local file system, the function [`fixup_dflt()`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/mappers/mod_dir.c#L171) will run, using the `FallbackResource` to determine which document should be loaded instead.

However, when a resource *can* be mapped to the local file system and it's a directory, it will attempt to resolve the document by running [`fixup_dir()`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/mappers/mod_dir.c#L224); this function iterates over the list of `DirectoryIndex` values until it finds the first suitable document.

In my case, the configuration has an empty list of `DirectoryIndex` values, so `fixup_dir()` will fail and a 404 is returned.

The following patch works for me ([PR](https://github.com/apache/httpd/pull/5)):

```
static int dir_fixups(request_rec *r)
{
    if (r->finfo.filetype == APR_DIR) {
-        return fixup_dir(r);
+        if (fixup_dir(r) != OK) {
+           /* use fallback */
+           return fixup_dflt(r);
+        }
+
+        return OK;
    }
    else if ((r->finfo.filetype == APR_NOFILE) && (r->handler == NULL)) {
        /* No handler and nothing in the filesystem - use fallback */
        return fixup_dflt(r);
    }
    return DECLINED;
}
```

It basically tries `fixup_dflt()` after `fixup_dir()` failed.

#### Update 2015-04-21

A [fix](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1675103) has been submitted to the project, scheduled for 2.5; it may be ported to 2.4 as well.

#### Update 2015-05-18

The fix has been [reverted](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1679620) because:

> [...] it [at least] causes `FallBackResource` to kick in before `mod_autoindex` might have kicked in.

I'm still trying to figure out how to avoid this kind of situation.

Comment: I would say the error is in `fixup_dir()` ignoring the FallbackResource.

Comment: @RickyBeam Yes, but technically `fixup_dir()` shouldn't know about `fixup_dflt()`, so imho it's better to fix it "higher up" :)

Answer (score 7):

Your configuration should be correct.

The problem, strangely enough, seems to be **mod_deflate**.

After having reproduced your configuration successfully here (*not* getting a 404), I also got the 5 second delay. However, I noticed that when the UA omits `gzip` from its Accept-Headers, the page is displayed/received instantaneously. You can test this for yourself with `wget`.

Interestingly, further debugging with `strace` shows that apache sends the contents of your `FallbackResource` to the socket of your client without noticeable difference in delay for *both* cases. This is also evident on the wire, where a reply paket is sent from the server to the client after the HTTP Request without any notable delay<sup>1</sup>.

It seems that when using mod_deflate in this case however, the UA doesn't know when the data sent by the server ends, and thus does not render anything before the TCP connection times out<sup>2</sup> and is forcibly closed by the server. This is compliant to HTTP/1.0, where a closed connection signifies end-of-content.

For **HTTP/1.1**, the server has other [means available to signal the end-of-content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) – *but none of which seem to happen here*.

Wether the bug lurks in mod_dir or mod_deflate however, is beyond my available time right now. I got it to work flawlessy by disabling gzip compression; as a workaround until the issue is fixed for good, you can selectively disable gzip.

<sup>1</sup>) This tells us that the problem does not stem from unflushed buffers on the server.
<sup>2</sup>) By default, the timeout is 5 seconds with apache - that's where your 5 seconds are from.

Comment: Thanks. The 5s delay issue is secondary to my main problem, I've updated my question with how to reproduce the issue locally.